# How can i get current url of the page in c# without the querystring param?

Tags: c#, url

How can i get current url of the page in c# without the querystring param?

I am capturing the Url of the page using `Request.Url.ToString()`. However this method gives me a modified URl because my Url containes Query string parameters.

So the following URL

http://www.example.com/Products/tabid/85/catid/Notebooks-414/Default.aspx

is rendered as

http://www.example.com/Default.aspx?TabId=85&catid=Notebooks-414

How can i get the URL as we see it in the browser?

Comment: I'm not 100% on this, but I'm pretty sure you can't.  What is likely happening is that some flavor of .htaccess is rewriting the url before it gets to your program, and so the second url is what ACTUALLY gets there.  Having said that, since you're translating the url in the .htaccess, you should in theory be able to translate it back in your serverside code.

Comment: Looks like you are using url rewriting of some sort... (clearly some tags are lacking from the post)... `Request.RawUrl` *may* help... Or grab header directly.

Comment: Yes.`Request.rawurl` worked for me